# tomcat server : Is Tomcat server must be restarted everyday?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using Tomcat server for my java based Application .

My question is that , is the server is not restarted for every day , its giving wrong results (Means the functionality isn't working ) , but as soon as the server is restarted , it is working fine .

I am very much confused about this unpredictability of results given , please tell me is such behaviour possible ??

Ours is a web service application using Apache CXF .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a bug in your own application and not by a bug in Tomcat. There is no reason for Tomcat itself to restart it every day.

Since you didn't say anything about what exactly goes wrong, it is not possible to help you with your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I am very much confused about this unpredictability of results given, please tell me is such behaviour possible?

There are any number of reasons why this might happen, pretty much all of which will end up pointing to bugs in your code. It's most likely to be resource leaks - memory leaks (e.g. adding things to a statically-referenced collection somewhere), database connection leaks etc.

You should definitely track down what's going wrong - we can't really help you do so without more information about what constitutes "wrong results" or what your application is doing. It *shouldn't* be necessary to restart the server every day.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat does not need to be restartet every day. I have Tomcat servers that run for weeks without problems. There must be a bug in your web applications that causes the incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably is your application having bugs that related to static variables or concurrency whereby the state of your application is affected by previous requests.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have TomCat set up as service on your machine?  It might be an idea to do this and make the recovery on the service automatic.